# Wordpress Timber Display Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I'm using Timber for my Wordpress theme and for some time now I've noticed that Timber does not show the content of new pages created.

Here is an example of my structure:

I have a **work.php** page that contains the following context:

```
        $context = Timber::get_context();

$args = array(
    // Get post type project
    'post_type' => 'project',
    // Get all posts
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    // Order by post date
    'orderby' => array(
        'date' => 'DESC'
    )
);

$context['post'] = new TimberPost();
$context['works'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );

Timber::render( 'page-work.twig', $context );
```

Then I have a "**page-work.twig**" page retrieves an include "inc-work.twig"

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    {% include 'inc-work.twig' %}  
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the inc-work.twig include

```
<section class="l-homegrid lazy-scroll">
  {% for post in works %}
    {% if post.thumbnail %}
      <a href="{{post.link}}" class="l-basicgrid-work work">
        <article>
          <figure>
            <img data-src="{{post.get_thumbnail.src('full')|resize(800, 533)}}" alt="project {{post.title}}" class="lazy">
          </figure>
          <figcaption>
            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
          </figcaption>
        </article>
      </a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}      
</section>
```

I feel that my code is correct. However, the Custom Content Type "Project" is not displayed.
It's strange, because I use the structure without any problem for other pages of the same site ...

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What’s the slug of your Custom Post Type? Is it `work` or `project`? Are you sure that work.php is displayed? And did you realize that you’re rendering `page-graphic.twig`, but you list `page-work.twig` as the Twig view?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The slug is "work". Page-graphic.twig was copy/paste error. I do use "page-work.twig" but it still don't work :-/

Comment: Ok, so you use `{% for post in works %}` in your Twig file, but I don’t see where you add `works` to your context. You add `graphics`, though. Might this be the problem?

Comment: Sorry if I haven't read my code before to post.

But online, the "work.php" file has : 
`$context['post'] = new TimberPost();
$context['works'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );
Timber::render( 'page-work.twig', $context );
`

But anyway, nothing it is rendered...

Comment: Do you get any output if you use `{{ dump(post) }}` right after `{% for post in works %}`?

Comment: @Gchtr I don't get anything. The page don't load the content of works even adding `code {{ dump(post) }}`

Comment: Well then I assume it could be something with your query, especially your `meta_query` array. If you remove `meta_query` temporarily, do posts show up then? Does the meta field `project_category` really contain a string `graphic` in your database, or is it the ID of a custom taxonomy?

Comment: Graphic is a value from a ACF (advanced custom field). I changed work.php by `code     $context = Timber::get_context();

    $args = array(
        // Get post type project
        'post_type' => 'project',
        // Get all posts
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        // Order by post date
        'orderby' => array(
            'date' => 'DESC'
        )
    );

    $context['post'] = new TimberPost(); 
    $context['works'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );

    Timber::render( 'page-work.twig', $context );` Well, I copy paste the actual work.php code into my first post!

Comment: So is it working now? Or are you still stuck?

Comment: Nope. Still not working. I looked to my theme (from timber starter theme https://github.com/timber/starter-theme), but everything looks good... I still don't understand where that problem come from

Comment: Just to be sure, can you re-save your settings **Settings** > **Permalinks** and check if it works then?

Comment: My permalinks are set to "post name". But even saving them again, the work page do not appear. I wonder if there is not a php / twig tag that is not closed. Or a problem with an htaccess file...

Comment: Okay. It’s really hard to tell at this moment what the problem could be. I’m afraid I can’t help you in sorting this out :/, sorry.

Comment: I discovered that installing SEO wordpress plugin, the header wasn't working. I wonder if the problem could come from the head structure. How should it be?

Comment: Good question! If you uninstall all plugins, does it still not work? With *head*, dou you mean the `<head>` tag or the **header.php** file in your theme?

Comment: I was thinking about the <head> tag ! I try to uninstall plugins

Comment: I unistalled plugins. I just left the plugins Timber ACF and ACF repeater fields (otherwise the site would mostly don't work). I wonder if the problem could not come anyway from ACF! At the end, the content from the custom post type "projects" are not displayed on the page "work"...

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue not that you are passing `$context['post']?`

Have you tried just changing the code to

```
{% for work in works %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Just to make sure that there is no conflicting variables in the context?